# LightDM won't boot after changing graphics card

Tags: xorg, graphics, lightdm

I changed my graphic cards from nvidia to a radeon R200 and now LightDM won't start even though I installed the new drivers.

I'm using Arch.

Can anyone please help me?

EDIT:
I can't copy the logs because I can't open my browser on my computer, for the lightdm logs I have "greeter display server failed to start" (I have lightdm-greeter-gtk) and also "no screens found". For the x-0.log file for the xorg logs I have "Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section".

Comment: Hi, these types of problems can be super frustrating so I feel your pain. In order for us to help you, you are going to need to add as much detail to your post as possible, As a start, what have you tried? What do the logs say? What package supports your new card and is it installed?

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm not so experienced with all the graphical echosystem so I've tried some random things like editing my xorg.conf file to update the graphical ddriver I'm grabbing the logs now, just a sec

Comment: I can't copy the logs because I can't open my browser on my computer, for the lightdm logs I have "greeter display server failed to start" (I have lightdm-greeter-gtk) and also "no screens found" for the x-0.log file
for the xorg logs I have "Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section"

Comment: It's almost certainly a missing/misconfigured driver. This is a good place to start: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ATI#Selecting_the_right_driver

Comment: @user1794469 can't thank you enough, turns out I was really using the wrong driver (I was supposed to use radeon instead of amdgpu). problem solved!

Comment: @user1794469 could you please post this in a separate answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is a missing or wrong driver. The arch wiki is a great source for how to solve these problems:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ATI#Selecting_the_right_driver

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: I was using amdgpu driver instead of radeon, also had to install the xf86-video-ati package